# Angular Nested Controller Reference to Child

Tags: angularjs

I've got two controllers: `TaskManageController` and `TaskFormController`. The `TaskFormController` has function to present it (modally) and the `TaskManageController` has an "+" button to add. Currently the `TaskManageController` is a parent of the `TaskFormController`. How can I call `present` on the child controller when clicking the "+" button in the parent controller?

```
<div ng-controller="TaskManageController AS manage">
  ...
  <a ng-click="manage.add()">+</a>
  <div ng-controller="TaskFormController AS form">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ng-init` to setup a reference to the child controller then use the reference in your manage controller:

```
<div ng-controller="TaskManageController AS manage">
  ...
  <a ng-click="manage.add()">+</a>
  <div ng-controller="TaskFormController AS form" ng-init="manage.form = form">
    ...
  </div>
</div>

// TaskManageContoller
this.add = function() {
  if (this.form) { this.form.present(); }
}
```